# Python Keyboard module

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a very simple keylogger but when I run the program, it throws me an error I can't decode.
It says: ArgumentError: argument 3: : int too long to convert. I can't understand why, I take it my key_presses arguments are being converted (in this case their not) into ints, but why are they not? here's the full error traceback: https://gyazo.com/2995334b1859724df213e7e39033fc81

```
import keyboard

file = open("Tips.txt", "w")

keyboard_loop = True

while keyboard_loop is True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + a"):
        file.append("w")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("b") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + b"):
        file.append("b")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("c") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + c"):
        file.append("c")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("d") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + d"):
        file.append("d")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("e") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + e"):
        file.append("e")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("f") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + f"):
        file.append("f")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("g") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + g"):
        file.append("g")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("h") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + h"):
        file.append("h")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("i") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + i"):
        file.append("i")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("j") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + j"):
        file.append("j")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("k") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + k"):
        file.append("k")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("l") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + l"):
        file.append("l")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("m") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + m"):
        file.append("m")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("n") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + n"):
        file.append("n")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("o") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + o"):
        file.append("o")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("p") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + p"):
        file.append("p")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + q"):
        file.append("q")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("r") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + r"):
        file.append("r")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("s") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + s"):
        file.append("s")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("t") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + t"):
        file.append("t")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("u") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + u"):
        file.append("u")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("v") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + v"):
        file.append("v")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("w") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + w"):
        file.append("w")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("x") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + x"):
        file.append("x")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("y") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + y"):
        file.append("y")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("z") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + z"):
        file.append("z")
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question. Also please consider using a loop instead of a ton of `if` clauses.

Comment: Added the full error traceback

Comment: Please add the traceback as text, not as an external image.

Comment: Bug report about this: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/186